# Android Calcualtor: taller screen and more marginal to the Edge

Tags: javascript, android, android-layout, calculator

Hi I am now making for the layout for an android calculator display, and have just imported "display-7 ttf for the display. The numbers can be displayed in the screen properly with the new font, but I dont know why after using the new font, the height of the Display screen become shorter and less marginal to the edge.

What is more is that the Preview in Eclipse Graphics Layout is still proper shown, but Display in the Emulator is shortened.

In short, I would like to have a taller screen and more marginal to the edge.

The layout code is as follows. Would there be anyone suggest for the amendments? many thanks!

**The code for font in the Main Activity:**

```
Display = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ansEditText); 
Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/digital-7 (italic).ttf"); 
Display.setTypeface(face);
```

**Relevant Layout code:**

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/ansEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_span="5"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:textColor="@color/display_text_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/display_text_size"
        android:textStyle="bold" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in your custom font the letters have other size than in the default font, it is normal to see the difference. But the Display doesn't change size, it is given by the hardware properties/emulator settings, only the EditText changes.

So I see 2 options

1. Wrap your layout in a ScrollView/HorizontalScrollView and make it as
   large as you want
2. Change the EditText properties (e.g. a smaller
   textSize could give you the desired effect)

I hope I understood the problem correctly (a picture would be useful) and my answer helps you.